# certbot certificate request - connection refused

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, certbot

I get an error by certbot, that the connection has been refused while trying to create a certificate. I checked the DNS entry and it has the correct server IP.

When I try to call up the domain, the browser also shows a connection refused. At least nginx should be running correctly and show wordpress I would guess? Why is my connecting being refused?

```
MPORTANT NOTES:
certbot      |  - The following errors were reported by the server:
certbot      |
certbot      |    Domain: retronexus.net
certbot      |    Type:   connection
certbot      |    Detail: Fetching
certbot      |    http://retronexus.net/.well-known/acme-challenge/YQzSQsdAAhqG45A5xAL3tJ4dMrsmTVfcKQVGNzT1lvs:
certbot      |    Connection refused
certbot      |
certbot      |    Domain: www.retronexus.net
certbot      |    Type:   connection
certbot      |    Detail: Fetching
certbot      |    http://www.retronexus.net/.well-known/acme-challenge/K-KuvzQCJWC-k_2VyJJoeSmP1HQcZE71g6giBvWSCJs:
certbot      |    Connection refused
certbot      |
certbot      |    To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
certbot      |    entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
certbot      |    contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
certbot      |    your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
certbot      |    firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
certbot      |    client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
certbot      |    that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.
```

also when I ping the domain, I get the correct IP displayed. Is there any other configuration to be made?

The DockerCompose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    networks:
      - rn-network

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:5.5.3-fpm-alpine
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=$MYSQL_USER
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_PASSWORD
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=$MYSQL_DATABASE
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
      - ./wordpress/wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
      - ./wordpress/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini      

    networks:
      - rn-network

  webserver:
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    image: nginx:1.15.12-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
      - ./wordpress/wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
      - ./wordpress/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini      
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - rn-network

  certbot:
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    image: certbot/certbot
    container_name: certbot
    volumes:
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
    command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/html --email EMAIL --agree-tos --no-eff-email --staging -d retronexus.net -d www.retronexus.net

volumes:
  certbot-etc:
  wordpress:
  dbdata:

networks:
  rn-network:
    driver: bridge
```

The nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name retronexus.net www.retronexus.net;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    root /var/www/html;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off; access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all;
    }
    
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
}
```